# LInux reserve memory for later allocation c++

Tags: c++, linux, memory-management

Is there a possibility to reserve memory for later allocation in a c++ program?

Background:
I'm working on Debian with Preempt RT patch. My program uses roughly 100MB memory. ALl pages are prevent from swapping with mlockall(). There are mainly 2 running threads, one run in real time and don't allocate memory. The other thread runs with slightly lower priority and allocate/free memory. 
In some rare situations a background process allocates all free memory and the system is starting swapping. Now my 'fast' thread want a little piece of ram. Now the kernel give me that new little piece BUT from swap. So my program is interrupted with an huge latency, let say 3sec.

Question:
Is there an way to reserve memory, let say 200MB. If my program will allocate it is definitely possible without swapping?

Comment: I don't understand.  If all your pages are locked in memory, how do they get swapped out?  If your *fast* thread needs some *extra* memory (eg because it is growing its stack), the solution is to make sure that grow the stack beyond it's maximum at startup, and then lock the whole stack.

Comment: But you said that your real time thread doesn't allocate memory.  If you mean it only allocates a little bit of memory, and not often, then you need to make sure that it grabs memory from an allocater that returns memory pre-locked by the background thread.

Comment: all my actual pages are working fine. but  my _fast_ thread want to allocate new pages on the heap. There is free memory, but only in swap on disk, not in physical ram. So the kernel interrupts my _fast_ thread for quite a while, swap some any other page to disk, give me that new page in ram. at this moment, not earlier, `mlockall(MCL_FUTURE)` will prevent this page to get swapped out.

Comment: @flunk: So why not just allocate at program start?

Comment: because it is not sure, how much menory is needed. within the fast thread, allocation/freeing is triggered by events. depending on inputdata, the allocation size is determined

Comment: Fundamentally you *cannot* only allocate as much memory as you need *and* have virtual memory available in RAM for your real-time thread to use.  Pick one.  (I would pre-allocate a configurable amount of memory, and let the users figure it out.)

Answer (score 1):

Even if you allocate all the memory you need, at the beginning of your program, the case you afraid of is that ANOTHER process will use memory. Unless you are the only process on that machine, there will always be another running process. Therefore the solution you want is a "reserved" RAM space that no one but your process can access. Which mean the kernel will never swap this space into HD (and therefore the kernel won't perform any physical access).

fortunately, **it is impossible unless you change your kernel** and recompile it. Think about the possibility you have more than one process who "reserve" memory for themselves. If you have 4Gb RAM then you are stuck :(